# php mail() function not working after adding radio buttons

Tags: php, html, forms

So I have a website where the user can fill in a form and when they submit, it sends to information to my email. Before I added the list including radio buttons, it was actually sending it. I have never really coded in php before, as I focus mainly on HTML, CSS, and JavaScript. Here is the php code at the top of my home page...

```
<?php
if($_POST["submit"]) {

    $recipient="example@yahoo.com";
    $subject="Business Sign-Up Request";
    $senderName = $_POST["senderName"];
    $businessName = $_POST["businessName"];
    $phone = $_POST["phone"];
    $senderEmail = $_POST["senderEmail"];
    $website = $_POST["website"];
    $businessLicense = $_POST["businessLicense"];
    $businessOption = $_POST["businessOption"]; //before I added this line and the addition of this to the mailbody variable, it was working perfectly.

    $mailbody = "Contact Name: $senderName\n\nBusiness Name: $businessName\n\nEmail: $senderEmail\n\nPhone: $phone\n\nBusiness License: $businessLicense\n\nWebsite: $website\n\nBusiness Option: $businessOption";

    mail($recipient, $subject, $mailbody);


}
    $thankYou="<p>Thank you! Your message has been sent.</p>";
?>
```

Here is the form itself with the added radio buttons...

```
<div id="TestModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-12 float-right">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="text-center">
                    <form method="post" action="home.php" class="text-center businessSignupForm">
                        <div class="text-center modal-body">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-6">
                                    <div>
                                        <input class="w-100 py-1 px-2 businessSignUp-input mt-2" required name="senderName" placeholder="Name">
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        <input class="w-100 py-1 px-2 businessSignUp-input mt-2" required name="businessName" placeholder="Business Name">
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        <input class="w-100 py-1 px-2 businessSignUp-input mt-2" required name="phone" placeholder="Phone">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-6">
                                    <div>
                                         <input class="w-100 py-1 px-2 businessSignUp-input mt-2" required name="senderEmail" placeholder="Email Address">
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                         <input class="w-100 py-1 px-2 businessSignUp-input mt-2" name="businessLicense" placeholder="Business License (optional)">
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                         <input class="w-100 py-1 px-2 businessSignUp-input mt-2" name="website" placeholder="Website (optional)">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row mt-5">
                                <div class="card-deck w-100 px-0 mx-0">
                                     <div class="col-lg-4 col-12 px-0">
                                          <div class="card">
                                               <div class="card-body">
                                                    <h5 class="card-title"><strong>Basic</strong></h5>
                                                    <hr>
                                                    <p class="card-text">
                                                        <ul>
                                                            <li>Map Directory</li>
                                                            <li>Business Profile</li>
                                                            <li>420 Promotions</li>
                                                        </ul>
                                                    </p>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="card-footer pb-3">
                                                    <div class="mb-3 basic-price"> <strong>FREE</strong></div>
                                                    <input required name="businessOption" class="d-block m-auto" type="radio" value="Free">
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-lg-4 col-12 px-0">
                                            <div class="card w-lg-100">
                                                <div class="card-body">
                                                    <h5 class="card-title gold-title"><strong>Gold</strong></h5>
                                                    <hr>
                                                    <p class="card-text">
                                                        <ul>
                                                            <li>Map Directory</li>
                                                            <li>Business Profile</li>
                                                            <li>420 Promotions</li>
                                                            <li>Upload & Manage Menu</li>
                                                        </ul>
                                                    </p>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="card-footer pb-3">
                                                    <div class="mb-3 gold-price"><strong>$349/mo</strong></div>
                                                    <input required name="businessOption" class="d-block m-auto" type="radio"  value="Gold ($349/mo)">
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-lg-4 col-12 px-0">
                                            <div class="card">
                                                <div class="card-body">
                                                    <h5 class="card-title platinum-title"><strong>Platinum</strong></h5>
                                                    <hr>
                                                    <p class="card-text">
                                                        <ul>
                                                            <li>Map Directory</li>
                                                            <li>Business Profile</li>
                                                            <li>420 Promotions</li>
                                                            <li>Upload & Manage Menu</li>
                                                            <li>Top Ad Placement</li>
                                                            <li>Reveive Customer Orders</li>
                                                            <li>Business Insights & Analytics</li>
                                                        </ul>
                                                    </p>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="card-footer pb-3">
                                                    <div class="mb-3 platinum-price"><strong>Request Quote</strong></div>
                                                    <input required name="businessOption" class="d-block m-auto" type="radio"  value="Platinum (Requesting Quote)">
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-12">
                                        <input class="btn btn-primary mt-4" type="submit" name="submit">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I dont know if this makes a difference or not, but the page reloads when I click submit. But I never changed that from before so I don't know why it would make a difference now.

Comment: Have you tried var_dumping $_POST('businessOption') ?

Comment: You code is working ok for me. Can you check spam folder of your inbox please? Or do you get any error from the code?

Answer (score 0):

For some reason it actually started working when I got the modal-body to wrap the form instead of the other way around.